# Use imshow of matplotlib.pylab with a python ide?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ide, ipython, imshow

I tried to run example in [photutil](http://photutils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/photutils/getting_started.html#getting-started)

Everything works great except the line

```
plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray_r', origin='lower')
```

which does not raise an exception but no image is shown. I use the eric ide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `plt.show()` afterwards.

From the [Matplotlib FAQ](http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#use-show):

> When you want to view your plots on your display, the user interface backend will need to start the GUI mainloop. This is what [show()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show) does. It tells matplotlib to raise all of the figure windows created so far and start the mainloop. Because this mainloop is blocking by default (i.e., script execution is paused), you should only call this once per script, at the end. Script execution is resumed after the last window is closed.

Comment: i changed to plt.show(image) but again nothing displayed

Comment: Do **not** replace imshow with show. Read the quote carefully. First create the plot with plt.imshow, then *display* the figure with plt.show().

Answer (score 2):

```
# need to use matplotlib inline if want to show at jupyter Notebook
%matplotlib inline
plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray_r', origin='lower')
plt.show()
```