# Image does not show with matplotlib.pyplot with ipython or python

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, ipython

If I do the following commands in iPython or just Python,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
img=mpimg.imread('stinkbug.png')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
```

then nothing happens (no image appear anywhere).

But if I do the following commands:

```
import scipy.misc as misc
img=misc.imread('stinkbug.png')
misc.imshow(img)
```

then image appears inside separate window of `ImageMagick`.

Also, I can run ipython with qtconsole and will see image with first code.

What are the difference between two different ways of diplaying images? Can they be unified, i.e. work in similar way in both consoles? Is it possible to make first code work in normal ipython/python?

Comment: I believe this is related to [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34742842/3005167).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `plt.show(imgplot)` at the end of your code.

[image]

Comment: My bad, I got confused. Now everything is fixed and a screenshot has been attached.

Answer (score 1):

One line is missing to show the plot window:

```
plt.show()
```