# Why is voronoi_plot_2d not showing any plot?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, voronoi

I am trying to generate a Voronoi diagram using voronoi_plot_2d. Below is my code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d
points = np.random.random((10,2))
vor = Voronoi(points)
voronoi_plot_2d(vor)
```

But instead of getting a plot, I get something like this on my command prompt.

```
<matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0x0474F7B0>
```

Am I missing something? Help me.

Comment: You are missing `matplotlib.pyplot.show()` to show the figure. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34743272/3005167)

Comment: @kazemakase Thanks. Its working now.