# Displaying image with matplotlib in ipython

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

How can I display an image imported with numpy package using matplotlib in ipython?

It should be fairly easy with the command

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = np.array(Image.open('image.jpg'))

plt.imshow(im)
```

But the image does not show and I just get the output

```
<matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x7fb38e10ff10>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use imshow of matplotlib.pylab with a python ide?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34742842/use-imshow-of-matplotlib-pylab-with-a-python-ide)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must call `plt.show()` to actually bring up the windows.
You can get around this by using *interactive mode*. But for scripts it is better to simply call `show()` after completing all your plotting commands.

Answer (score 7):

In IPython or Jupyter notebooks, if you want to show images as inline in the notebook and not in a separate window, implement the code shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

im = np.array(Image.open('image.jpg'))

plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you need plt.show() when you use %matplotlib inline?